# How to find the admin/creator of a fan page on Facebook?

Tags: facebook-pages

I'm not looking for the Facebook Page ID. How can I find the owner profile who has created or manages the fan page of a person or company on Facebook?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot. I imagine that celebrity stalkers would love to be able to get to the accounts behind celebrity pages.

Comment: I'm also looking for that answer, I was searching for that in recent time. Most of the people say the same thing which is mentioned [here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/51988/). It exists some months before but now all are patched. So wait for any new method - Check the Hackers posts/news continuously. And also check for Business Manager method. (business.facebook.com)

Answer (score 3):

According to the Facebook Help team ([1](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200145925984857) [2](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200178514720240))

> Page admins are only visible if the page owner has featured them. To find out more information, you can view a page's Contact Info in the About section, or you can send the page a message.

Comment: See also: [How to find the admin of a Facebook page?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11683772)